# LINQ join - two objects by different "type" of parameters

Tags: c#, linq

I am learning how to use LINQ and have a trouble at one point.

I am building a simple currency converter. I have a `List<Currency> currencyList` which contain Currency objects with their name, code and actual rate (parsed from XML file).

Now, lets say, I want to get specific currencies. I have a `List<string> desiredCurrencies` containing the following currency codes `"EUR", "USD", "CHF"`. I make a query then:

```
var results = from c in currencyList 
              join dc in desiredCurrencies on c.Code equals dc 
              select new { c.Name, c.Code, c.Rate };
```

But the query result is empty. 
I know that if a made a new `List<Currency> desiredCurrencies` and then made `... on c.Code equals dc.Code ...` that would work. But is this possible to just have a string List with currency codes, join it alltogether and get a result?

I would be thankful also for an example how this query can be writted using Lambda expressions, as I am not familiar with them yet.

**EDIT:** Well, I've found a bug in my code. Basically, the XML parser did not parse all the currencies and those with codes `"EUR', "USD", "CHF"` were... missing. Sorry for bothering but thank you for your help and the Lambda expressions!

Comment: So `Currency.Code` could be `"EUR"` or `"USD"`? Then it should work. I also don't understand what you mean with _"if i'd made a new `List<Currency> desiredCurrencies` and then made ... `on c.Code equals dc.Code` ... that would work"_. What's the difference to the current code?

Comment: Fyi, with `Enumerable.Join` method syntax isn't pretty, i prefer query syntax then.

Comment: My thinking is then, that there are two objects with same property - `Currency.Code`. As I've seen in many examples (mostly something like joining `on Object1.Id` equals `Object2.Id`). In this case a have a `Currency.Code` property and a string to compare.

Comment: Your way of using a join wouldn't work in cases like currencyList is not a local list (such as an entitylist coming from a database).

Comment: @CetinBasoz: of course you can join in the database. But it even works if you join database entities with a local list which is not so obvious because it must be converted to SQL.

Comment: Not always, sorry. For example with Linq To SQL it doesn't have an implementation, does it? With EF it does have an inefficient implementation though.

Comment: @CetinBasoz: i've just tested it with Linq-To-Sql (.NET4). Works without a problem

Comment: Are you sure? I just did too and got this message "Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator", Would you mind sharing your code? I will give Northwind sample I tried.

Comment: This is the one that gave error:

       var ids = new List<int> {10250, 10254, 10255};
              var result = (from o in Orders
                          join i in ids on o.OrderID equals i
                           select o)
                        .ToList();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using lambda expressions :

```
var results = currencyList.Where(c=>desiredCurrencies.Contains(c.Code))
                          .Select(c=>new {c.Name, c.Code, c.Rate});
```

Comment: OP's approach is more efficient and should work also. So i assume that your approach won't work either for whatever reasons(f.e. `c.Code` wrong type).

Comment: @TimSchmelter Oh, yes you may be right. But he asked how to do it using lambda.

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = from c in currencyList 
              where desiredCurrencies.Contains( c.Code )
              select new { c.Name, c.Code, c.Rate };
```

In method syntax it would be:

```
var results = currencyList
              .Where( c => desiredCurrencies.Contains( c.Code ) )
              .Select( c => new { c.Name, c.Code, c.Rate });
```

Comment: Is this an effecient way? Just asking as @Tim Schmelter questioned the approach of abovelisted post.

Comment: Better than EF's implementation IMHO. Contains is implemented as an IN query, whereas EF implements it as a series of unioned data. It may look like it is efficient code wise, but when you try it in a real world application it is notoriously slow. So I mean inefficient speed wise at least (maybe it is just because EF is very slow).